# How can i add a value in an Array which is inside a struct (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have this Struct:

```
struct Event {
        var nameEvent: String
        var nameMagazi: String
        var objectId: String
        var typeEvent: NSArray
    }
```

and I use it to make a Dictionary with these four variables like this:

```
     for object in objects {

                            let post = object["idEvent"] as? PFObject
                            let post2 = post!["idMagazi"] as? PFObject
                            let post3 = object["eventType"] as? PFObject
                            let nameevent = post!["name"] as! String
                            let idevent = post?.objectId
                            let namemagazi = post2!["name"] as! String
                            let typeevent = post3!["EventName"] as! String
                            var count = 0
                            for index in 0...self.i {
                                if  self.events[index]?.objectId == idevent  {
                                    count += 1
                                    self.dump = index
                                }

                            }


                         if count == 0 {

       self.events[self.countids] = Event(nameEvent: nameevent , nameMagazi: namemagazi , objectId: idevent!, typeEvent: [typeevent])
                                self.countids += 1
                            }else{

  self.events[self.dump]!.typeEvent = [self.events[self.dump]!.typeEvent, typeevent]


          }

                            self.i += 1
                        }
```

As you can see if i find a duplicate i want only to add the typeevent to the existing the Array.

```
 self.events[self.dump]!.typeEvent = [self.events[self.dump]!.typeEvent, typeevent]
```

this line works but it's like it returns array inside another array like this:

```
(
        (
                (
                        (
                                (
                                        (
                        "\U0395\U03bb\U03bb\U03b7\U03bd\U03b9\U03ba\U03ac"
                    ),
                    mainstream
                ),
                hiphop
            ),
            house
        ),
        rnb
    ),
    Live
)
```

Comment: Your indentation is ... creative?

Comment: In order to encourage good answers you should format the question to have a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The best bet is to put your code into a  playground and see if it works. If not then you should trim/modify it until it does. That way someone can take your example and easily figure out the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @ColGraff  i will try to do it to my next questions! This code is a query that takes results from parse. My question doesn't need this query that's why i didn't completed all.

Comment: @AMomchilov  i didn't understand you. :/

Comment: Why do you say that? @AMomchilov

Comment: Because it's completly inconsistent and very unclear. I edited your question to fix it.

Comment: Ok thank you for the edit, but i don't think you had to vote down my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a value to the array `typeEvent` create a mutating function in the struct

```
struct Event {
  var nameEvent: String
  var nameMagazi: String
  var objectId: String
  var typeEvent: [String]

  mutating func addEvent(event : String) {
    typeEvent += [event]
  }
}
```

I changed `typeEvent` from type unspecified `NSArray` to the Swift native type `[String]`

Now you can write

```
var event = Event(nameEvent: "Foo", nameMagazi: "Bar", objectId: "Baz", typeEvent: ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"])
event.addEvent("delta")
event.typeEvent // -> ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta"]
```

Comment: Note that this is just syntactic sugar for "create a new struct and replace the old one with the new". Structs are [value types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID88) which can only be created and copied, they can't be modified. It might be clearer to do that rather than adding a function into the struct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't think to make  array like [string] i maybe just stuck. I will try your answer tommorow because i haven't access now!

Comment: @ColGraff That's not really true. From the documentation: *Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods. However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to **mutating** behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and **any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure** when the method ends.*

Comment: @vadian Yep, you're perfectly correct. I misunderstood how a mutating function works behind the scenes and further investigation cleared up my misconception. Thanks!